# Issue trying to access Date Picker on field in table using name

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In my project I have to convert all of my tables into Bootstrap dynatable format.  I am working on the page where I have a table and the user will be able to modify the status and Status date depending on check box.  For some reason I can not get the date picker to work on one of the columns in the table.  Here is a partial set up of the table:

```
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="flextable" id="updateResults">
    <table id="checkedTable" class="tablesaw tablesaw-stack table-responsive" data-tablesaw-mode="stack">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> SEL</th>
          <th>Schedule Number</th>
          <th>Contract Year</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Status Date</th>
          <th>Approval ID</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <c:forEach var="row" items="${Updresults}">
          <c:set var="sched" value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" />
          <c:set var="eftyear" value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" />
          <c:set var="EFTstatus" value="${row.getSTATUS()}" />
          <c:set var="schedcombo" value="${sched}${eftyear}" />
          <fmt:formatNumber var="schedTotl" value="${row.getTOTAL_AMOUNT()}" pattern="$##,###,##0.00" />
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input style="width:50px;" type="checkbox" id="holdselectedSched" name="selectedSched" class="pullchecked" value="<c:out value=" ${schedcombo} "/>"/>
            </td>

            <td id="ModifyScheduleNumber">
              <c:out value="${row.getSCHEDULE_NUMBER()}" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <c:out value="${row.getEFT_CONTRACT_YEAR()}" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <select style="width:80px" id="ModifyStatus" name="ModifyStatus_<c:out value=" ${schedcombo} "/>" class="form-control">
                <c:forEach items="${ModifyList}" var="statusValue">
                  <option value="${statusValue}" <c:if test="${statusValue == UpdCMDStatus}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                    >${statusValue}</option>

                </c:forEach>
              </select>
            </td>
            <td>
              <input class="form-control" name="ModifyStatusDate_<c:out value=" ${schedcombo} "/>" type="text" value="${row.getSTATUS_DATE()}" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <c:out value="${row.getAPPR_HUD_EMPLOYEE()}" />
            </td>
          </tr>
        </c:forEach>

      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
```

Here is my function to access the datepicker:

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name^='ModifyStatusDate_']").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Is the problem trying to use the wild card in the `<input>` in the function or an issue with the dynatable set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it without the single quote.

```
$(function() {
  $("input[name^=ModifyStatusDate_]").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
  });
});
```

Comment: That didn't work.  My original code was accessing the datepicker by using an empty class, calling the class in the <input> box tied to the <td> and adding a  $( ".date_picker" ).datepicker({  function call.  it was working great but for some reason when I modified using the bootstrap dynatable stuff it stopped working.  I am wondering if I need to now get the date_picker class inside this <span> with the ID of ui-datepicker-div?

Comment: @hammerva this should work, unless you are messing up something else. the selector is right..

Comment: No actually this worked.  I found the issue.  I need to do the datepicker function processing after I create the dynatable.  Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Or try using this, I am suggesting this because you said `Nikki9696's` answer is not working for you. Try looping through each element and then applying the plugin one by one.

```
$(function() {
  $.each("input[name^=ModifyStatusDate_]",function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
     dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    });
  });
});
```